# Magento 2.2.1,In admin The store view functionality not display on header

Tags: magento2, backend, store-view

I can not switch the store view from admin because there is missing store view functionality.
Please see the screenshot. And let me know how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue..How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It manages from the backend configuration. Disable the Store mode from admin.

> Go to Admin->Store->Configuration->General->General->Single-Store Mode->Select Dropdown "No".

Comment: It's working. you saved my time!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the default store view in which you are currently working on. If you want to see another store view, you have to create a new one. Follow these steps:

1. Head to **Stores > Settings > All Stores**.
2. Click on **Create Store View**.
3. Select parent store in the **Store** field. Enter **Name**, **Code**,
   and **Sort Order** appropriately.
4. In the **Status** field, select **Enabled** to activate the view.
5. Finally, click on **Save Store View** button.

Comment: Its a backend configuration. Change Stores->Configuration->General->Single-Store Mode-> Enable -> No